# How to update an UI design of all item in FlatList on selection or click of a single item in the list

Tags: react-native

How to update an UI design of all item in FlatList on selection or click of a single item in the list. I have tried possible outcomes i can think of also flatlist property extradata only works if there is change in data otherwise it doesn't work, also passing value from child component to parent and changing one of the property of flatlist to re render

This is the code in which i change the data array on callback from child component :

```
export default class CombinedScreenList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      page: 1,
      seed: 1,
      error: null,
      refreshing: false,
      isLongPress: false,
      ref: false,
      index: 1
    };
  }
callBackFuncForChild = (passData) =>{ 

    this.setState({isLongPress: passData});
    this.setState({data: []});
    this.makeRequest();

}
async makeRequest(){
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
  }
  async componentWillMount(){
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
  }
  makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const { page, seed } = this.state;
    const url = `https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=${seed}&page=${page}&results=2`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: page === 1 ? res.results : [...this.state.data, ...res.results],
          error: res.error || null,
          loading: false,
          refreshing: false
        });
        //jsonResponseData = JSON.stringify(res.results);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error, loading: false });
      });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      // <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      //   <Text>{this.props.data}</Text>
      // </View>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          extraData={this.state.refreshing}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
               <ExpensesTileHeader content = {item} longPressParentFunc = {this.callBackFuncForChild} 
               isSelection = {this.state.isLongPress}/>
          )
          }
        />
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#extradata) of react-native flatlist shows

**extraData**

> A marker property for telling the list to re-render (since it implements PureComponent). If any of your renderItem, Header, Footer, etc. functions depend on anything outside of the data prop, stick it here and treat it immutably.

you can add extraData field as props in the flatlist

```
<FlatList
  extraData={this.state}
/>
```

and uponselection set `isLongPress to true` which triggers a change in state following rerender of the flatlist and in the renderItem  switch the ui styles according to `this.state.isLongPress` value

and in the callback function update your state in one function as

```
this.setState({
 isLongPress: passData,
 data:[]
})
```

Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: yup ! its done by extending childComponent to purecomponent and componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) function...thnks for your time and answer..